# Multiple redux-sagas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I use react-redux and redux-saga for API calls from [this](http://www.webpackbin.com/NkNhb8R3-) example. My target is to do another API calls with different urls and to use them in different pages. How to achieve that?

**Sagas:**

```
import { take, put,call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { takeEvery, delay ,takeLatest} from 'redux-saga';
function fetchData() {
    return  fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed")
    .then(res => res.json() )
    .then(data => ({ data }) )
    .catch(ex => {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex);
        return ({ ex });
    });
}
function* yourSaga(action) {
    const { data, ex } = yield call(fetchData);
    if (data)
    yield put({ type: 'REQUEST_DONE', data });
    else
    yield put({ type: 'REQUEST_FAILED', ex });
}
export default function* watchAsync() {
    yield* takeLatest('BLAH', yourSaga);
}
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield [
        watchAsync()
    ]
}
```

**App:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'BLAH'});
    }
    render(){
       return (<div>
            {this.props.exception && <span>exception: {this.props.exception}</span>}
            Data: {this.props.data.map(e=><div key={e.id}>{e.url}</div>)}

          </div>);
    }
}
export default connect( state =>({
    data:state.data , exception:state.exception
}))(App);
```

My target is to make another saga, which I will use in another component, and both to not mess with each other. Does that possible?

Comment: Per your comment on Github [here](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/178#issuecomment-249249953),
I've modified your example to show using two different API calls. You should be able to expand upon that to make it work: http://www.webpackbin.com/VkdjuU02Z

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Of course, that is the whole point of sagas.

A typical application will have multiple sagas waiting in the background, waiting for a particular action / actions (`take` effect).

Below is an example of how you can setup multiple sagas from [redux-saga issue#276](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/276):

`./saga.js`

```
function* rootSaga () {
    yield [
        fork(saga1), // saga1 can also yield [ fork(actionOne), fork(actionTwo) ]
        fork(saga2),
    ];
}
```

`./main.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'

import rootReducer from './reducers'
import rootSaga from './sagas'


const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

Comment: should I include anything here? export default connect( state =>({
    data:state.data , exception:state.exception
}))(App);

Comment: And how to define in component itself which saga properties it must get?

Comment: No, components are completely separated from sagas. You dispatch actions in components, sagas intercepts certain actions (using `take`). A bit similar to reducers.

Comment: could it better to use spawn here?  is there any reason to keep them linked to the root saga?

Comment: @bigmadwolf, if you want the rootSaga to terminate if a single child crashes. It depends on your use case - [more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438005/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-starting-rootsaga). Also, explicitly yielding `all` is better since [yielding array will be deprecated](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1073).

Comment: @yjcxy12 don't use fork, use spawn instead, ref: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RootSaga.html

Answer (score 33):

Redux Saga uses the `all` function in the recent version (0.15.3) to combine multiple sagas to one root saga for the Redux store.

```
import { takeEvery, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

...

function *watchAll() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery("FRIEND_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchFriends),
    takeEvery("CREATE_USER_REQUESTED", createUser)
  ]);
}

export default watchAll;
```

In the Redux store you can use the root saga for the saga middleware:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootReducer from './reducers';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

Comment: that is very helpful :)

Comment: When reading the api docs it says that the `all` method is similar to `Promise#all`. Here's quote _"Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to run multiple Effects in parallel and wait for all of them to complete"_. Is this a different method? Should I be running the `all` method if i just have a bunch of different saga's? Exporting a list of `yield takeLatest()` or an `all([ yield takeLatest() ])`

Answer (score 7):

This has changed a bit since last answers were posted. The preferred way to create root saga, as documented at https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RootSaga.html, is using `spawn`:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield spawn(saga1)
  yield spawn(saga2)
  yield spawn(saga3)
}
```

`spawn` is an effect that will disconnect your child saga from its parent, allowing it to fail without crashing its parent. This simply means that even if one saga were to fail, the `rootSaga` and other sagas will not be killed.
There is also way of recovering sagas that fail (more info on that is available in the link mentioned above).

Comment: Working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

As best practice first of all you should create API files that have all the API calls you would like to have. then imported the API  you need right in the saga you need to work on then use the same saga for multiple tasks. Then after doing that you should create rootSaga which handles all the saga as guys answered for you already to fork each of your sagas and use All in an array then you're done(the best practice because will show you a lot of fields that were a bit blurry as the flow of redux-saga ...)

Comment: Answer is a bit difficult to read. Please consider editing to increase readability